# ¿Por qué este código indica que Usuario o contraseña no valido?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```html
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$op = $_GET['op'];

if($op=="in"){
    $sql = mysqli_query($success,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE user='$user' AND password='$password'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1){
        $qry = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $qry['user'];
        $_SESSION['nama'] = $qry['nama'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $qry['password'];
        $_SESSION['level'] = $qry['level'];
        if($qry['level']=="Admin"){
            header("location:home_admin.php");
        }else if($qry['level']=="user"){
            header("location:home_user.php");
        }
    }else{
        ?>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            alert('Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrecta. ¡Inténtalo de nuevo!');
            document.location='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}else if($op=="out"){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    unset($_SESSION['level']);
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Quiero saber si esta bien el código,ya que me dice que el usuario o contraseña no válido.

No sé si lo estoy asociando bien. Soy nuevo en esto y he investigado que ese codigo es con un php  obsoleto, o no se si lo estoy escribiendo bien.

Comment: Creo que no estas asignando nada a user y password, asi que apenas corre, te dira que no hay nada, imprime los valores para que los puedas ver, y saber que estas comparando.

Comment: Excorpion, amigo me puedo contactar con tigo?, me puedes ayudar. llevo horas con este codigo.

Comment: Yo llevo una semana con el mio XD

Comment: Si no funciona, lo más probable es que el código no esté bien. Di directamente cuál es el problema que te encuentras. Lo primero es saber cómo lo invocas, puedes probar a imprimir los valores de `user`, `password`, `in`.

Comment: Yo lo dijo @SJuan76, se salta la verificacion

Comment: @Excorpion y lo veo, pero es mucho mejor si lo dice desde el principio y no hay que buscarlo. Mira el edit de alfabravo.

Comment: Tu pregunta necesita que le **añadas** el código del formulario que está enviando esos valores que lees al comienzo. Si se salta la validación es porque no contienen lo que crees que contienen. De paso, hacer un `print_r($_POST)` no sobra, para que veas qué está llegando por POST

Comment: Como ya han dicho los compañeros, depura tu código, puedes usar `var_dump($cualQuierCosa);` para verificar el estado de `$cualquierCosa`. Por otra parte, veo que mezclas `$_GET` y `$_POST` en tu código. Debes normalizar, usando uno u otro según el método del formulario o lo que sea que uses para mandar los datos. Eso en algunos contextos pueden fallar y aunque no falle, no es correcto mezclar métodos en la recogida de datos. Además, si la password fue hasheada al insertar, debes usar ahora `password_verify` para comprobarla.